# Rcpp function default values in header file

Tags: r, rcpp

I whant to specify **default values** for my Rcpp function arguments **in header file**. So I have header file **foo.h**:

```
#ifndef foo_H
#define foo_H
#include <Rcpp.h>

int foo(int k = 3);

#endif
```

I also have **foo.cpp** file:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
//'Some description
//'
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int foo(int k)
{
  return(k);
}
```

I compile the package and use this function from R:

```
foo()
```

Then I get error "argument "k" is missing, with no default" while I am expecting 3 to be returned.

Please help we to figure out how to define Rcpp default values in header file.

Will be very greatfull for help!

**P.S.** I need to specify default values in header file only and not any other place. It is clear to me how to specify default values in .cpp but I need to specify them in .h.

Comment: Due to the way Rcpp attributes work, you must have the default values set in the function definition so that they can propagate into the R wrapper. There are hacky ways around the limitation but they involve creating two definitions.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a header file.  You could put everything in foo.cpp

Comment: I've encountered the same problem as @Bogdan.  Even when I include the default values in the header definition, they don't appear in R.  I actually used the exact same files as Bogdan.  Calling 
    foo()
produces the error "argument "k" is missing, with no default".